# multisig exec executes the proposed transaction but does not transfer the funds

Tags: multisig

I have a multisig transaction that transfers funds from a msig account "mymultisig1a" to "partner1111a" and it seems to execute properly and generates a transaction id but does not actually transfer the funds.

this is all on the jungle test net

PRE TRANS BALANCES

------ SOURCE MSIG ACCOUNT ---------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get account mymultisig1a
created: 2019-10-22T22:17:49.000
permissions:
     owner     2:    1 partner1111a@owner, 1 partner2222a@owner, 1 partner3333a@owner
        active     2:    1 partner1111a@active, 1 partner2222a@active, 1 partner3333a@active
memory:
     quota:     4.296 KiB    used:     3.455 KiB

net bandwidth:
     staked:          2.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:               483 bytes
     available:        251.8 KiB
     limit:            252.2 KiB

cpu bandwidth:
     staked:          2.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             1.193 ms
     available:        91.45 ms
     limit:            92.65 ms

EOS balances:
     liquid:          100.0000 EOS
     staked:            4.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:           104.0000 EOS

producers:

--------TARGET ACCOUNT -------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get account partner1111a
created: 2019-10-22T22:15:36.000
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 EOS5c6B63vL2tiqKPe7qpRH5y1AmxL1r9xgEKbCujmGNdF1hztbut
        active     1:    1 EOS6GX1HKgmhbRgAiT3Y5qFCzj12b6SyRKje5sXANjgmkjvVS5b7H
memory:
     quota:     4.296 KiB    used:     3.543 KiB

net bandwidth:
     delegated:       2.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             2.186 KiB
     available:          250 KiB
     limit:            252.2 KiB

cpu bandwidth:
     delegated:       2.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             2.194 ms
     available:        90.45 ms
     limit:            92.65 ms

EOS balances:
     liquid:          100.0000 EOS
     staked:            0.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:           100.0000 EOS

TRANSACTION CODE AND OUTPUT

-------------propose trans---------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io multisig propose beermoney5 '[{"actor": "partner2222a", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "partner3333a", "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "mymultisig1a", "permission": "active"}]' eosio.token transfer '{"from":"mymultisig1a", "to":"partner1111a", "quantity":"2.00 EOS", "memo":"Give partner1111a some beer money"}' partner1111a

---return---

executed transaction: abc097a2ef74e0879db7aaa8ebef71c620f6561e118b2115cc5506c681f56494  264 bytes  207 us

## eosio.msig <= eosio.msig::propose          {"proposer":"partner1111a","proposal_name":"beermoney5","requested":[{"actor":"partner2222a","permis...

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet

------------review trans-----------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io multisig review partner1111a beermoney5

-----output-----

{
  "proposer": "partner1111a",
  "proposal_name": "beermoney5",
  "transaction_id": "ccf5c899d1f0d01cdcc412d1e3bcac35e3472f039741212e498f9a66e8b53ea3",
  "packed_transaction": "5c08b15d000000000000000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd01600273d8e5a8a59700000000a8ed323242600273d8e5a8a597604208e1aa99afa9c80000000000000002454f5300000000214769766520706172746e6572313131316120736f6d652062656572206d6f6e657900",
  "transaction": {
    "expiration": "2019-10-24T02:11:40",
    "ref_block_num": 0,
    "ref_block_prefix": 0,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [{
            "actor": "mymultisig1a",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "mymultisig1a",
          "to": "partner1111a",
          "quantity": "2.00 EOS",
          "memo": "Give partner1111a some beer money"
        },
        "hex_data": "600273d8e5a8a597604208e1aa99afa9c80000000000000002454f5300000000214769766520706172746e6572313131316120736f6d652062656572206d6f6e6579"
      }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": []
  }
}

------------partner2222a approve trans----

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io multisig approve partner1111a beermoney5 '{"actor": "partner2222a", "permission": "active"}' -p partner2222a@active

---output-----

executed transaction: 06e74d30ddd2ed56d7f13d8732dbdd1b2eaf9e8e475a87fb5901d5cdee58d1ef  128 bytes  215 us

## eosio.msig <= eosio.msig::approve          {"proposer":"partner1111a","proposal_name":"beermoney5","level":{"actor":"partner2222a","permission"...

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet

----------partner3333a approve trans----

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io multisig approve partner1111a beermoney5 '{"actor": "partner3333a", "permission": "active"}' -p partner3333a@active

----output------

executed transaction: 5251070a512ee51bfe60e9dba7e27135d168f48d950e05ddf532ddb0b413c80d  128 bytes  205 us

## eosio.msig <= eosio.msig::approve          {"proposer":"partner1111a","proposal_name":"beermoney5","level":{"actor":"partner3333a","permission"...

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]

---------exec trans--------------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io multisig exec partner1111a beermoney5 -p partner1111a@active

---------exec trans--------------------
executed transaction: d669c434378689680ce3bc63883f28a7786387fdf9f2533a1246d6b95489b07a  160 bytes  317 us

## eosio.msig <= eosio.msig::exec             {"proposer":"partner1111a","proposal_name":"beermoney5","executer":"partner1111a"}

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]
-------------done----------------------

POST TRANSACTION BALANCES

----------SOURCE MSIG ACCOUNT ---------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get account mymultisig1a
created: 2019-10-22T22:17:49.000
permissions:
     owner     2:    1 partner1111a@owner, 1 partner2222a@owner, 1 partner3333a@owner
        active     2:    1 partner1111a@active, 1 partner2222a@active, 1 partner3333a@active
memory:
     quota:     4.296 KiB    used:     3.455 KiB

net bandwidth:
     staked:          2.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:               475 bytes
     available:        251.8 KiB
     limit:            252.2 KiB

cpu bandwidth:
     staked:          2.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             1.383 ms
     available:        91.26 ms
     limit:            92.65 ms

EOS balances:
     liquid:          100.0000 EOS
     staked:            4.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:           104.0000 EOS

producers:

---------- DESTINATION ACCOUNT --------------

cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get account partner1111a
created: 2019-10-22T22:15:36.000
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 EOS5c6B63vL2tiqKPe7qpRH5y1AmxL1r9xgEKbCujmGNdF1hztbut
        active     1:    1 EOS6GX1HKgmhbRgAiT3Y5qFCzj12b6SyRKje5sXANjgmkjvVS5b7H
memory:
     quota:     4.296 KiB    used:     3.543 KiB

net bandwidth:
     delegated:       2.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             2.564 KiB
     available:        249.7 KiB
     limit:            252.2 KiB

cpu bandwidth:
     delegated:       2.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             2.647 ms
     available:           90 ms
     limit:            92.65 ms

EOS balances:
     liquid:          100.0000 EOS
     staked:            0.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:           100.0000 EOS

------explorer output -------------

[image: explorer output for the exec action]

Is this a bug?   Seems like this should be impossible without raising an error.

I know that's alot,  but I'm stumped.    Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your msig is a symbol precision mismatch. You need to use 4 decimals.

```
"quantity":"2.0000 EOS"
```

instead of

```
"quantity":"2.00 EOS"
```

Comment: Bingo!   Thanks!   But I think not raising and error on the multisig exec is a bug.    This would cause a bunch of problems in a real world scenario.   I'll report this as an issue to the dev team.

Comment: THere's an exception thrown. You just need to know where to look for it. Take a look here: https://jungle.eosq.app/tx/d669c434378689680ce3bc63883f28a7786387fdf9f2533a1246d6b95489b07a and here: https://jungle.eosq.app/tx/1e1ea2f9ea0b05ff28cb9cafbfec12933ada2447a779c7cb2652165ac05a23e5 to see the exception thrown. And pls mark the answer as correct :p

Comment: Still,  I would consider this a bug,  even if you document that you need to disregard the exec function return status until you check another source for the real execution status.   Imagine how much trouble this could cause in a production environment?   Anyway,  thank you for solving this!!!

Comment: Have you opened a issue and can you add a link here?

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/364 ,    not a very satisfying resolution